# How do i solve this error Unexpected Application Error! Cannot set property value of #<TextFieldBase2> which has only a getter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using typescript, react-hook-form along with yup validation and fluent ui. Whenever i am trying to submit a form i am getting this error ' Unexpected Application Error! Cannot set property value of # which has only a getter ' . [image]

I am getting this error while i submit the form with all the values. How do i approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code it's hard to say but if this happened to me I would check my types and make sure they correspond with my input props and how the values are set.

second with hook form it is important to remember that you can only use input fields that are 'registered' or 'controlled' so if you accidentally forget to register an input, errors like this can occur.